# Remove duplicates items using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the below list (list of product) that has duplicate elements

I want to remove all duplicates from the list based on the version and date property

This means, if there's a diplicate element, i get the one that has state actif, if no one has state actif then i get the one with the recent date

```
public class Product {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private Version version;

    private Instant createdDate;

}
```

example of list of product:

```
[
   {
      "name":"1",
      "version":{
         "state":"Actif",
         "name":"1.0.0"
      },
      "createdDate":"01/01/2020"
   },
   {
      "name":"1",
      "version":{
         "state":"A faire",
         "name":"3.0.0"
      },
      "createdDate":"01/01/2020"
   },
   {
      "name":"1",
      "version":{
         "state":"Archiver",
         "name":"2.0.0"
      },
      "createdDate":"02/01/2020"
   },
   {
      "name":"2",
      "version":null,
      "createdDate":"01/01/2020"
   },
   {
      "name":"2",
      "version":{
         "state":"Archiver",
         "name":"2.0.0"
      },
      "createdDate":"02/01/2020"
   },
   {
      "name":"3",
      "version":{
         "state":"Archiver",
         "name":"2.0.0"
      },
      "createdDate":"01/01/2020"
   }
]
```

The output should look like:

```
[
   {
      "name":"1",
      "version":{
         "state":"Actif",
         "name":"1.0.0"
      },
      "createdDate":"01/01/2020"
   },
   {
      "name":"2",
      "version":{
         "state":"Archiver",
         "name":"2.0.0"
      },
      "createdDate":"02/01/2020"
   },
   {
      "name":"3",
      "version":{
         "state":"Archiver",
         "name":"2.0.0"
      },
      "createdDate":"01/01/2020"
   }
]
```

How can we do this using the stream and Collectors?

Comment: You posted a JSON. You cannot use JSON natively in JAva. How does the POJO looks like?

Comment: If you have a stream, there's probably a `.distinct` call you could make. However, you first need to figure out how to convert to and from JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using of `toMap` collector by `merge` function.

```
BinaryOperator<Product> merge = (p1, p2) -> {
       if (p1.getVersion() != null && p2.getVersion() != null) {
            if (p1.getVersion().getState().equals("Actif")) return p1;
            else if (p2.getVersion().getState().equals("Actif")) return p2;
        } else {
            return p1.getCreatedDate().isAfter(p2.getCreatedDate()) ? p1 : p2;
        }
        return null;
    };

listOfProduct.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Product::getName, Function.identity(), merge))
                .values();
```

Comment: what you mean by Product::getProduct ?

Comment: @AymenKanzari,  my answer doesn't help you?